# My script is messing up values enterred into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I don't know why this is happening, so I decided to ask you, guys :)

First, I have a form that loads values of the entry I want to edit. Everything seems to be working fine at this point. The values are "loaded" into the inputs correctly.

```
 echo '<form action="edit.php?action=edit_proceed&id='.$id.'" method="post">
Názov: <input type="text" name="nazov1" class="edit" value="'.$data[nazov1].'"><br>
Druhý názov: <input type="text" name="nazov2" class="edit" value="'.$data[nazov2].'"><br>
Poznámka: <input type="text" name="poznamka" class="edit" value="'.$data[poznamka].'"><br>
Kontajner: <input type="text" name="kontajner" class="edit" value="'.$data[kontajner].'"><br>
Velkosť: <input type="text" name="velkost" class="edit" value="'.$data[velkost].'"><br>
Cena: <input type="text" name="cena" class="edit" value="'.$data[cena].'"><br>
Cena s dopravou: <input type="cena2" name="nazov1" class="edit" value="'.$data[cena2].'"><br>
Obrázok: <input type="text" name="obrazok" class="edit" value="'.$data[obrazok].'"><br>
Nezobrazovať: <input type="text" name="not_show" class="edit" value="'.$data[not_show].'"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upraviť"></form>';
```

Then, I load variables from $_POST for easier future use: `$nazov1 = $_POST["nazov1"]`, and so on. I quadruple-checked the variable names - they are enterred correctly.

The last step of the process is the query:

```
$query = 'UPDATE rastliny2 SET nazov1="'.$nazov1.'", nazov2="'.$nazov2.'",
poznamka="'.$poznamka.'", kontajner="'.$kontajner.'", velkost="'.$velkost.'",
cena="'.$cena.'", cena2="'.$cena2.'", obrazok="'.$obrazok.'", not_show="'.$not_show.'"
WHERE id="'.$id.'" ';
```

However, the value of nazov1 is edited to the value of cena2 and cena2 is 0. I have no clue, what could be wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct this first

```
Cena s dopravou: <input type="cena2" name="nazov1" class="edit" value="'.$data[cena2].'"><br>
```

it should be

```
     Cena s dopravou: <input type="text" name="nazov1" class="edit" value="'.$data[cena2].'"><br>
```

Look at your type type="cena2"

Answer (score 0):

In your form code you have a mistake:

```
<input type="cena2" name="nazov1" class="edit" value="' ....
```

This should be `type="text"` and `name="cena2"`, I assume.

Comment: Wow, I am really blind. Thanks a lot. I was staring at it for at least 15 minutes. Thank you very much :)